# Make reproducible simulation runs with nw:generate-preferential-attachment?

Tags: netlogo

I want to make a reproducible simulation run which starts with the generation of a network using `nw:generate-preferential-attachment`.

I used random-seed to set the seed for random number generation. This works fine when `min-degree` = 4 or less. Surprisingly, it does not work for `min-degree` = 5 or higher. When I clear-all, set the seed, and generate the network and randomly place nodes, this always looks different, with `min-degree` >= 5. It looks identical (as it should) for `min-degree` <=4. I provide a minimal example.

```
extensions [nw] 
to setup 
  clear-all
  random-seed 1
  nw:generate-preferential-attachment turtles links 100 5
  ask turtles [setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
end
```

Replace the "5" in line 5 with "4" and run setup two times each to see the difference.

Is there a way to make this work also for larger `min-degree`? What is the reason for this difference?

Comment: sounds like a bug in the `nw` extension. I'd suggest reporting it at https://github.com/netlogo/nw-extension/issues

Comment: It was indeed a bug and now is fixed: https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension/issues/192